# change the structure of a pandas dataframe, move header to a column

Tags: python, pandas

I got a dataframe like below from an API:
[image]

I want to change its structure to have a dataframe with a column for time, a column for name and a column for the float value. Any hints?

Comment: Please post your data as code and not as screenshots.

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

Input data:

```
>>> df
       Time  23-30-17 19:00:00  12-30-17 20:00:00  12-30-17 21:00:00
222  County                  1                  2                  3
227    Farm                  4                  5                  6
```

```
df = df.set_index('Time').stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Name', 'Time', 'Value']
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
     Name               Time  Value
0  County  23-30-17 19:00:00      1
1  County  12-30-17 20:00:00      2
2  County  12-30-17 21:00:00      3
3    Farm  23-30-17 19:00:00      4
4    Farm  12-30-17 20:00:00      5
5    Farm  12-30-17 21:00:00      6
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is what you're asking (not a whole lot of info provided), but you can try and transpose the dataframe.
This will flip rows to columns and columns to rows

```
df.T
```

Comment: Can'r simply  use Transpose